# automating daily file update for landing page

Tags: file, audio, automation, auto-update

I want to create a simple website for a friend who does a daily story/prayer. How do I set it up to automatically change the landing page file for these daily messages? Further, if I want the previous day's file to move to an archive page simultaneously how best to program?